# Is it possible to repeat a tiled background with an angle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tile

I know you can use a small png tile-able pattern image to create a background, but, is it possible to give it an angle?, let say, 20 degrees?.

So instead of having all your tiles one next to each other but with the same height, they are placed following a line.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/

try this

Comment: That seems to do the job, thanks, why not answer?, you think it could not work?

Comment: You could also try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/7bbM5/). Very similar to the article linked in the above comment. That article uses rotate while this fiddle uses skew.

Comment: Mhhh but skew is not the same.

Comment: When you skew a tile/image, you are altering it's vertices, when you only change the degree of placement, the tile is unaltered, only rotated. Let me know if I understood something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image

You could try the procedure described here

Comment: I like that answer mate. That is a very good solution but please make a demo and post code here. Otherwise, it may get flagged as "link only" :(